# Kotlin nullable receiver of type List in Map?

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin, accessing a value from a map gives different receiver type on different ways of accessing it

The type of the Map is of type LinkedHashMap

If I don't null check in this line

`println("Morning: ${daypartEvents[Daypart.MORNING].size}")`

compiler gives the error

Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type List?

But, if the same result is tried to achieved by iterating through the map with the forEach function like this

`daypartEvents.forEach { (daypart, events) -> println("$daypart: ${events.size}") }`

It doesn't want me to null check it.

Even if I do null check it it says

Unnecessary safe call on a non-null receiver of type List

I know the question is poorly framed so please bear with me

What I want to know here is why the value of the map which is of type List is nullable at first and non-nullable later.

Full code for clarity

```
enum class Daypart {
    MORNING, AFTERNOON, EVENING
}

data class Event (
    val title: String,
    val description: String? = null,
    val daypart: Daypart,
    val duration: Int
)

fun main() {
    
    val event1 = Event(title = "Wake up", description = "Time to get up", daypart = Daypart.MORNING, duration = 0)
    val event2 = Event(title = "Eat breakfast", daypart = Daypart.MORNING, duration = 15)
    val event3 = Event(title = "Learn about Kotlin", daypart = Daypart.AFTERNOON, duration = 30)
    val event4 = Event(title = "Practice Compose", daypart = Daypart.AFTERNOON, duration = 60)
    val event5 = Event(title = "Watch latest DevBytes video", daypart = Daypart.AFTERNOON, duration = 10)
    val event6 = Event(title = "Check out latest Android Jetpack library", daypart = Daypart.EVENING, duration = 45)
    
    val events = mutableListOf<Event>(event1, event2, event3, event4, event5, event6)
    
    
    val daypartEvents = events.groupBy {
        it.daypart
    }
    
    print(daypartEvents::class.simpleName)
    
    
    println("Morning: ${daypartEvents[Daypart.MORNING]?.size}")
    
    daypartEvents.forEach { (daypart, events) ->
        println("$daypart: ${events.size}")
    }
    
}
```

I am still new to Kotlin and this was one of the practice exercise from the Android Jetpack Compose for Beginners course at developer.android.com

Comment: It does, that was a clear explanation, thanks.

Comment: @Sweeper I think this should be an answer, not a comment, even if it's that simple :)

Comment: As an aside, when the key is an enum, and you're concerned about performance of the resulting map, consider grouping to an EnumMap, which is more efficient. `events.groupByTo(EnumMap(Daypart::class.java)) { it.dayPart }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, a map may or may not have a specific key. So even though the type of your values is non-nullable, expressions accessing a value by its key may return null if the key is not in the map. The compiler doesn't analyze the code deep enough to understand that, in your specific case, the key `Daypart.MORNING` will always be there.

This is why in your first case `daypartEvents[Daypart.MORNING]` is nullable.

The second case is different. You're not trying to access a specific key in the map. Your iterating on all mappings (entries) that are actually in the map right now. For those, we know that their value cannot be null, so no need for null checks.

Going back to the first case, you can also choose to get an exception (failure) instead of null in case the key is not present. This is done by using `daypartEvents.getValue(Daypart.MORNING)` instead of the bracket syntax, [as pointed out by @JSmonk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77913563/1540818). The error message will say which key is not in the map. This is useful when you're sure that they key will always be in the map at that point, or just if you intend to fail anyway and this error suits you.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to "hide" the null check, you can use [Map#getValue](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/get-value.html) instead of the `get` operator.
Like [this](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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):

```kotlin
println("Morning: ${daypartEvents.getValue(Daypart.MORNING).size}")
```